# bootstrap button group styling with button_to

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having trouble in styling the bootstrap button group using button_to.

[image: sample image]

As shown above, I would like to have something like in the bottom, but currently I'm having a problem with button with "4" when using "button_to" helper.

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">2</button>        
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">3</button>
<%= button_to "4", {:action => "new", :id => 1}, :class => "btn btn-default" %>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">5</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">6</button>
</div>
```

please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up with following code.
It works fine, now.

```
<%= link_to "4", {:action => "new", :id => 1}, class: "btn btn-default", role: "button" %>
```

Answer (score 3):

The rails form helper `button_to` generates a form around the button element, and this form has css of `display:block`

I solved this by adding this css:

```
div.btn-group form{
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about setting the div's styling to display: inline?

Comment: used button_tag with link_to inside. it works somehow, but it is actually press link inside the button, which is not what i want.

Comment: button_to creates a form element and it's not being styled is my best guess. What about just styling the class btn btn-default?